# Multiple GLView in iPhone games

Tags: ios, user-interface, opengl-es

Should I ever think about using multiple `GLViews` in an `iphone OpenGL` game? For instance, I am about to start creating the start menus using `OpenGL` for my game. My plan is to use the same `GLView`, but should I consider using another `GLView`?

Comment: I am considering it from two aspects. First, does it have any `performance impact`? Second, it the right `coding method` to do the `start menus` for a game? It's my first game & I want to make sure I am following the coding best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app is not exactly a game, but it uses 3 `GLViews` on the screen at once (theoretically more, but three is the current).  There is nothing wrong with doing this, but the documentation says that mixing `GLViews` with other views slows down processing by a bit.  I can't remember where I read that though.

Long story short I would say avoid it if you can.  If your app is entirely GL based then why not make it all in one?  My app is not entirely GL based so I needed multiple "windows" of GL drawing.